# What is causing the errors in my abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract

```
public abstract Shape {
    public abstract void draw();
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ArrayList shapes = new ArrayList(); 
        shapes.add(new Shape()); // Line ONE
        shapes.get(0).draw(); // Line TWO
    } 

    public class Square extends Shape { 
        public void draw () {
            System.out.println(“The square is being drawn.”);
        }
}
```

Can someone help explain the error in line ONE? Is it fixable?

Even if the line above is fixed, the line Line TWO will still generate an error. How can I fix line two?

Comment: 1) If you get an error, please always put the error message within your post. 2) You can not instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: @Korashen you can't instantiate it because it is abstract, it's not abstract because you can't instantiate it, though

Comment: To fix it replace new Shape() with new Square()

Comment: @Stultuske Of course! Guess I got my wording wrong. I removed that part from my comment to avoid any further mistakes. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: `shapes.add(new Square());` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an abstract class, which is what you do with your `new Shape()`

Abstract classes are bases on which you build, you extend them and create concrete classes, which you will be able to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

Three errors:

1) `public abstract Shape {` should be `public abstract class Shape {`

2) `shapes.add(new Square()); // Line ONE` because Shape is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

3) `((Square)shapes.get(0)).draw(); // Line TWO;` because shapes.get(0) returns an Object instance therefore a cast to Square is required.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are four errors:

1) `public abstract Shape {` should be `public abstract class Shape {`

2) `shapes.add(new Shape()); // Line ONE` because Shape is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

3) `shapes.add(new Square()); // Line ONE` We cannot use `non-static` method in a `static` scope until you mark it static.

4) `((Square)shapes.get(0)).draw(); // Line TWO;` because shapes.get(0) returns an Object instance therefore a cast to Square is required.